# How do you get the HTTP host with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the hostname from an HTTP request using Laravel 5, including the subdomain (e.g., `dev.site.com`). I can't find anything about this in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#request-path-and-method), but I would think that should be pretty simple. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Good news! It turns out this is actually pretty easy, although Laravel's Request documentation is a bit lacking (the method I wanted is inherited from [Symfony's `Request` class](https://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)). If you're in a controller method, you can inject the request object, which has a `getHttpHost` method. This provides exactly what I was looking for:

```
public function anyMyRoute(Request $request) {
    $host = $request->getHttpHost(); // returns dev.site.com
}
```

From anywhere else in your code, you can still access the request object using the [`request` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request), so this would look like:

```
$host = request()->getHttpHost(); // returns dev.site.com
```

If you want to include the http/https part of the URL, you can just use the `getSchemeAndHttpHost` method instead:

```
$host = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost(); // returns https://dev.site.com
```

Answer (score 27):

There two ways, so be careful:

```
<?php

    $host = request()->getHttpHost(); // With port if there is. Eg: mydomain.com:81

    $host = request()->getHost(); // Only hostname Eg: mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 13):

## laravel 5.6 and above

```
request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()
```

Example of use in blade :

```
{{ request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request()->url();`

Also you can dump the complete `request()->headers();`

And see if that data is useful for you.

Comment: It's `request()->header()` not `request()->headers()`