# Get REFERRER in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a newbie in laravel, so maybe please don't beat me :-)

I try to get the referrer inside a controller in this way

```
$from=Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
```

As result, I get this error

> Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::server() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

At the top from the controller is

```
namespace Common\Auth\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Common\Settings\Settings;
use Common\Core\Controller;
use Common\Core\BootstrapData;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Common\Auth\User;
```

Hope somebody can show me how I can get the referrer a give me a little lesson about that.

Thanks a lot.

**Update.**

In the meantime i've add "**function name(Request $request)**" to my function
and inside the function "**$this->request = $request;**"

Now i can access with "**$this->request->ip();**" some informations.

If i try to echo that "**$this->request->header('HTTP_REFERRER')**" nothing will display?

Comment: Keep in mind that the official HTTP_REFERRER header is spelled incorrectly as HTTP_REFERER (notice it doesn't have a double R there).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the referer from the headers of the request:

`$uri = $request->header('referer');`

In which `$request` is the default injected `Illuminate\Http\Request`

[Read more on the headers of the request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#request-headers)

Answer (score 1):

To get the full URL for the previous request, use the Laravel helper function

```
url()->previous();
```

You can also access it via the URL facade

```
URL::previous();
```

Be sure to resolve the import if you are using the URL facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/urls#accessing-the-current-url)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why laravel request facade not working like above, but you can get header like this

```
function example(Request $request) {
    dd($request->header('HTTP_REFERRER'));
}
```

make sure your method accessed from route

Comment: "make sure your method accessed from route" sorry what do you mean about that?

Comment: like on web.php Route::get('/example', 'class@example');

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the referer directly from PHP by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
// with request helper function from anywhere in your application
$from = request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

// with request method. this return http:// part too
$from = $request->getHttpHost();
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835651/10482374

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the URL::previous() handle in [UrlGenerator@previous](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php)
reveal accessing the referrer with `$this->request->headers->get('referer');`

Answer (score -1):

please change this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

with:

```
use Request;
```